# Отображение картинок в pjax

Tags: yii2, pjax

yii2, использую pjax для фильтров поиска, возникла необходимость в gridview отображать ссылку на картинку.

как вывести саму ссылку понятно, вопрос в другом: почему это работает так криво и как это исправить?

без pjax все работает отлично.

ссылка:

[image: ссылка]

результат клика лкм:

[image: результат клика лкм]

результат открытия в новой вкладке:

[image: результат открытия в новой вкладке]

вывожу так:

```
'attribute' => 'url',
'format' => 'html',
'value' => function($model){
    return Html::a($model->url, Url::to(["uploads/uploads/products/$model->url"]));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для ссылок которые не должны загружаться через xhr (а они даже с правильным content-type отображаются как текст) нужно добавить аттрибут

`data-pjax="0"`

Comment: все работает (дополненный ответ), спасибо